# How to select the first timestamp that appears in a distinct query in SQL?

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, distinct, ansi-sql

So I have data as follows:

```
USER                TIMESTAMP    DATA
0001  2021-05-18 20:40:06.251   alpha
0002  2021-05-18 22:40:06.251    beta
0002  2021-05-18 21:40:06.251   gamma
0003  2021-05-18 19:40:06.251   delta
0004  2021-05-18 01:40:06.251 epsilon
0003  2021-05-18 20:40:06.251    zeta
```

And I want to create a list of all DISTINCT USER names as well as their associated DATA of the FIRST TIMESTAMP.

The result should look like this:

```
USER                TIMESTAMP    DATA
0001  2021-05-18 20:40:06.251   alpha
0002  2021-05-18 21:40:06.251   gamma
0003  2021-05-18 19:40:06.251   delta
0004  2021-05-18 01:40:06.251 epsilon
```

Now this question is resolved by doing the following:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM df a
    WHERE a.TIMESTAMP IN (
            SELECT min(TIMESTAMP)
            FROM df AS b
            WHERE a.USER = b.USER
        )
```

BUT, this is computationally taxing on my server so I need a different approach. I have been trying joining the df on itself ON USER AND TIMESTAMP but I haven't gotten it yet, any idea for a faster method? I am doing this in Snowflake btw...

Comment: It's actually standard SQL:ANSI , please ignore any mention of MySQL @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try window functions;

```
select df.*
from (select df.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from df
     ) df
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is good, but i still would prefer to see the Join of the DF with ITSELF on USER AND TIMESTAMP